# Construct a minimal DFA

Tags: automation, finite-automata

Construct a DFA for the set of string over {a, b} such that when length of the substring "aba" is divided by 3 leaves remainder 2 i.e, |w|aba = 2(mod 3).

Comment: Is this a homework question? You haven't given any indication of what you've tried or what kind of level you are at with finite automata.

Comment: Does this mean to say, that the number of occurrences of the substring aba in w is congruent to 2 modulo 3? So ababa would be in the language but aba and abababa would not be?